# Mysql view of 2 tables with count of rows (with only 1 create statement)

Tags: mysql

For create a view of 2 tables with count of rows I have done this way (2 views)

1st view

```
CREATE VIEW view_tmp
AS
SELECT  id_user, 
        COUNT(*) totCount
FROM    t1
WHERE   data < DATE_ADD( curdate( ) , INTERVAL 16 DAY ) 
AND     alert = 1 GROUP BY id_user
```

2nd view

```
CREATE VIEW view_final
AS
SELECT  t1.id_user,
        t2.email,
        COALESCE(s.totCount,0) totCount
FROM    t1
        INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.userid = t1.id_user
        LEFT JOIN view_tmp s ON s.id_user = t2.userid
WHERE   data < DATE_ADD( curdate( ) , INTERVAL 16 DAY ) 
AND     alert = 1 GROUP BY id_user
```

I'd like to create the "view_final" using a single statement "create" without using a temp view, is it possible to do? Thanks.

Comment: Can u give the desired out put here.

Comment: desired output - view_final t1.id_user, t2.email, totCount.